# "Darum ---- ich mir ein Auto."

Tags: verb

How should I complete the following sentence:

> Ich mochte nicht mit der Bahn fahren. Darum ---- ich mir ein Auto.

Is "mieten" the correct answer? If yes, why "mir"? Is it a reflexive verb?

I found this example for [the verb](http://www.dict.cc/?s=zu%20mieten&failed_kw=zumieten):

> Ich möchte gerne ein Auto **mieten**.

Comment: Because it's not on Ray's list, I must note that we primarily use *dingen* in Yiddish. Is that dialectic anywhere in German?

Comment: Never heard *dingen* as a verb... But probably *sich verdingen* is derived from it :)

Comment: Does that mean "to rent" then?

Comment: "Darum dingen ich mir ein Auto."?? Does sound very wrong to me as a native and makes no sense. "Ich verdinge mich als Lehrer" means "i work as a teacher", so I dont think this has anything to do with each other.

Comment: "I rent myself out as a teacher". "I rent a car". It might not sound right in modern German, but that's the verb we use in Yiddish. If it sounds so wrong to you maybe it's because you've inserted the infinitive form directly into the blanks. Try the same thing with the verbs suggested by Tohuwawohu (leihen, mieten, nehmen) and you'll see they're just as wrong, or just as right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Mieten* is completely fine, and you will usually use it without a reflexive pronoun (*mir*), because the usual sense of *mieten* is to rent something for your own use. You *can* insert the reflexive pronoun if you want to emphasize that you did rent the car *for your own* use, to satisfy *your* needs. The same is true for *leihen* — “ich habe das Buch ausgeliehen” just describes the act of borrowing (as opposed to buying/renting/stealing it), or the fact that you're not the book's *owner* (“ich habe es nur geliehen”). “Ich habe es *mir* ausgeliehen” means “*I needed it*, so I just took it, planning to return it after usage/as soon as possible”.

You can insert other verbs, too, depending on the focus of the sentence. In your case, *mieten* is the most neutral and correct choice. Other choices are:

- *leihen* would imply that there was no obligation to pay for the car's usage (but often people don't distinguish between these two alternatives);
- *nehmen* leaves open the legal details (payment) when used with an indefinite article (“einen Wagen nehmen”). Otherwise, with a definite article (“den Wagen nehmen”), it would usually imply that you used your *own* car: “Bist Du mit der Bahn gekommen?” — “Nein, ich habe den Wagen genommen”, but not vice versa: “Ich habe den Zug genommen” doesn't imply it was *your* train — you would use the definite article here anyway (selecting the definite vs. indefinite article is a problem on its own).

Comment: "ich habe das Buch ausgeliehen" is ambiguous, it can also mean that you have lent this book to somebody: "Ich habe das Buch gerade nicht, ich habe es ausgeliehen".

Comment: The superflous reflexive use is the same as the English:

"I got me a beer."

vs.

"I got a beer."

Comment: @JürgenA.Erhard In this case I would prefer "Ich habe das Buch *ver*liehen."

Answer (score 8):

I don't think there is a single "correct" answer. It could be...

- lieh
- klaute
- kaufte
- gönnte
- verordnete
- wünschte
- erhoffte
- erbat
- ...

as well, depending on what the context of those sentences is...